# background service makes app crash after unlocking the real device

Tags: android, service, crash

I am running a background service which checks for some updates from the server every 2 hours in my android app and it works fine so long as the device is the not in the locked state. But once I lock my phone and unlock again I see my device displaying the message that my app has crashed. What could be the real reason behind it. Does it need some permissions to be declared. Could anyone suggest me as to why this is happening.

Comment: The crash log would be infinitely helpful in telling you what the root cause is.  Also, the mechanism you are using the time the polling (AlarmManager, Handler, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It can be happening from several causes. But I gonna give my guess: **are you taking in consideration the case that your app fails to reach the server?** What I mean is that I'm guessing that when you lock your phone, or close it in some way, it can be closing your connection and your app can be crashing because it fetchs the server without connection. Its only a very broad guess...

Comment: but i am using a broadcast receiver to start service only when net connection exists and when it is automatically lost then I am stopping the service.

Comment: Hmm... by "lock my phone", you mean closing it (from sliding keyboard mobiles)? Or its just/only calling the lock screen? Are you sure that the crash is from your assumpted cause? In some situations, the crash is from layout issues. Also, in your code/emulator it crashes in the same manner? If yes, what is your logcat messages? If no, is all configurations (code version, service registration in manifest, etc) ok?

Comment: i figured it out...I read the logcat messages and figured what needed to be done and finished it